# strftime bug in Sqlite on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, strftime

Running Android 4.1.2.

The following should work according to SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

```
String sql = "SELECT strftime('%m', MyDate) FROM MyTable";
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(sql);
c.moveToFirst();
String s = c.getString(0); // returns null
```

However, the returned data is always `null`. If I change the query to `SELECT MyDate FROM MyTable` then it does indeed return a valid date so I can assure you that my database contains correct data.

**Q:** Am I facing a bug in the `rawQuery` method or have I done something wrong?

Comment: What format is `MyDate` in? If the format of `MyDate` is 2012-12-15 (for example) you'll need to use... `"SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', MyDate) FROM MyTable"`. In other words, adjust the first parameter of `strftime(...)` to match the format of `MyDate`.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like it doesn't like this format: `2012-12-15T12:34:56.789`. If I remove the 'T' it seems to work.

Comment: @Squonk: The first parameter of `strftime` is its *output* format; its input must always be in one of the few [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) formats.

Comment: @l33t: Support for `T` was added way back in SQLite [3.2.0](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_2_0.html). In theory, this should work in any Android version.

Comment: @CL. : But the SQLite definitions and the Android implementation is a different thing. I've seen plenty of posts and comments here on SO which suggest the Android implementation doesn't work WRT SQLite. Personally I just use raw SQL statements with Android rather than using functions like `strftime(...)`.